# Why "Disable" or "Restart" methods are not working (Using WMI in C#)

Tags: c#, wmi, system.management

I just wrote 3 different codes. One of them works fine. But other two, don't work and throw an `ManagementException` with the message:

> This method is not implemented in any class

Here is the code that works fine:

```
string ComputerName = "localhost";
ManagementScope Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\CIMV2", ComputerName), null);

Scope.Connect();

string WQL = String.Format("SELECT * FROM Win32_Volume");
ObjectQuery Query = new ObjectQuery(WQL);
ManagementObjectSearcher Searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Scope, Query);

foreach (ManagementObject ClassInstance in Searcher.Get())
{
    ManagementBaseObject inParams = ClassInstance.GetMethodParameters("Defrag");
    ManagementBaseObject outParams = ClassInstance.InvokeMethod("Defrag", inParams, null);
    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}", "DefragAnalysis", outParams["DefragAnalysis"]);
    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}", "ReturnValue", outParams["ReturnValue"]);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Here is the code that is not working and throwing the exception (See that is basically the same code) The one thing that had changed is the WMI class used. The exception happens on InvokeMethod.

```
string ComputerName = "localhost";
ManagementScope Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\CIMV2", ComputerName), null);
Scope.Connect();
string WQL = String.Format("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity");
ObjectQuery Query = new ObjectQuery(WQL);
ManagementObjectSearcher Searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Scope, Query);

foreach (ManagementObject ClassInstance in Searcher.Get())
{                
    ManagementBaseObject inParams = ClassInstance.GetMethodParameters("Disable");
    ManagementBaseObject outParams = ClassInstance.InvokeMethod("Disable", inParams, null);
    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}", "ReturnValue", outParams["ReturnValue"]);
    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}", "rebootNeeded", outParams["rebootNeeded"]);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

I also tried to use the method "Reset" instead of "Disable". it does not work. But this time, the exception occurred on `GetMethodParameters`. It said that this method was not implemented in any class.

```
string ComputerName = "localhost";
ManagementScope Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\CIMV2", ComputerName), null);
Scope.Connect();
string WQL = String.Format("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity");
ObjectQuery Query = new ObjectQuery(WQL);
ManagementObjectSearcher Searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Scope, Query);

foreach (ManagementObject ClassInstance in Searcher.Get())
{                
    ManagementBaseObject inParams = ClassInstance.GetMethodParameters("Reset");
    ManagementBaseObject outParams = ClassInstance.InvokeMethod("Reset", inParams, null);
    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}", "ReturnValue", outParams["ReturnValue"]);
    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}", "rebootNeeded", outParams["rebootNeeded"]);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

I need a code that enables and disables PNP devices, also, I need to use WMI classes to keep the same standard of the rest of the code, so I need to use namespace `System.Management`;

Comment: Try `ManagementBaseObject outParams = ClassInstance.InvokeMethod("Disable", null, null);` , OR `ManagementBaseObject outParams = ClassInstance.InvokeMethod("Disable", null);`; the reason because there is no input parameter for the Disable method. Also, for invoking the reset method, check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394353(v=vs.85).aspx . It explicitly says that **Reset 
Not implemented. To implement this method, see the Reset method in CIM_LogicalDevice.** I feel, this would suffice: `ManagementBaseObject outParams = ClassInstance.InvokeMethod("Reset", null, null);` would do.

Comment: I've never attempted these things; I was just curious as to how these things work, so I checked the API link and have **guessed the above point based upon their documentation**.

Comment: Hi. The first try I got another exception... "Invalid method"

Comment: The second try, I couldn't compile...

Comment: Interesting, if I try ManagementBaseObject outParams = ClassInstance.InvokeMethod("Disable", null, null); I got the message "Invalid method", and if I try ManagementBaseObject outParams = ClassInstance.InvokeMethod("Reset", null, null); I got the message "This method is not implemented in any class"

Answer (score 0):

The code for disabling devices is correct, but you need to run it with administrator rights. Without the admin permission, I'm getting System.Management.ManagementException 'Generic failure'.